# How to install php Imagick library with docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, imagick, laravel-sail

I'm just working on a laravel project which runs on docker using sail.For a feature i need to create functionality which can create thumbnails for pdf's.I figured out it is possible to done using php Imagick class/library.But unfortunately I'm struggling to install it on the project.Anyone knows how to install it using docker?Really appreciate.
This is the Dockerfile.

```
LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) like this:

```
FROM php:8.0

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions imagick
```